# Why does a radiator valve require more torque after a few turns?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heating-systems

I'm automating a non-thermostatic household radiator valve, by replacing the knob with a DC motor and adding some support structure. You can see the system at work here: https://www.instagram.com/p/BRQ8xS9gPPN/

The motor applies a constant torque and stops automatically when it stalls, i.e. when the valve can't turn anymore. The water flowing in the valve has a temperature of 60-62 degrees Celsius.

After a repeated stress test (fully open, wait 5s, then fully close, wait 5s, repeat), starting from a closed position and the radiator at ambient temperature, I noticed that the time required to open and close the valve had increased over time. It seemed like the valve is getting harder and harder to turn.

My strongest suspect is an effect of heat. If so, what could be happening? Is the valve opposing more resistance, or the motor providing less torque? Is it something that I have to take into account during regular use? What other causes could lead to this phenomenon?

Unfortunately I couldn't do other tests because some parts broke due to mechanical stress. Will update this post when I'll have more results.

Comment: Heat from the hot water could be affecting motor performance if the heat isn't being dissipated fast enough. Is the space the setup is in adequately ventilated?

Comment: The setup is the same as in the video linked, so I think the heat dissipation is enough. But I'll try to measure the temperature on the motor and check is there's a direct relationship with the motor performance.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure nothing happened to the valve during the stress testing.